# Plot several densities with geom_density, but fill using continuous variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a grouped density plot using ggplot. Usually, you would use `aes(fill = variable_to_group_by)` to obtain several densities, each colored/filled by `variable_to_group_by`.
However, I would like the fill of each density distribution to take the color of a continuous variable (which is unique within each group) instead of the discrete factor that I am using for grouping.

So, I would like to have a distribution per `cut` as below, but the 'fill' color of the distributions should rather be by the continuous variable `mean_carat`(made below).

```
diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  mutate(mean_carat = mean(carat)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = price, fill = cut, color = mean_carat)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To fill the area under the curve, use `fill`, not `colour`.  `colour` defines the colour of the line used to draw the density.

Comment: Thanks, but yeah I know, but I cannot use a continuous variable for `fill` if I still want to group by `cut` :-)

Comment: OK.  So your question is not "How do I fill the area under the curve according to one column?" But rather "How do I fill the area under the curve according to two columns?".  The answer is `fill = interaction(cut, mean_carat)`.  But this is the same as `fill=cut` in your example because the value of `mean_carat` is the same for all rows with a common value of `cut`.  Because you've calculated the mean `carat` grouped by `cut`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `group` aes you could group by `cut` but fill by `mean_carat`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  mutate(mean_carat = mean(carat)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = price, group = cut, fill = mean_carat)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: OP wants to group by both `cut` and `mean_carat`. But see my comment about why this makes no sense in this case.

Comment: @Limey I'm afraid you misunderstood the question. See the OPs comment on my answer.

Comment: I'm glad OP has obtained what they wanted, but their answer to you appears inconsistent with their answer to me: 'I *still* want to group by cut". [My emphasis.]